# Discord.js Command Bot Error: bot is going crazy

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I am a beginner at Node.js Coding and recently coded my bot on repl.it

I have specific commands for moderation, basically warn and mute.
When I am running the bot, then write something in chat (everything, just '.' for example) it says I have to mention and then warn himself and then warn again for his previous warn msg and etc. I don't know if you did understand but anyway.

Here is my code:

```
client.on("message", async (message) => {
 let victim = message.mentions.users.first()
 if(!victim) message.reply("mention someone to warn.")
 else {
 let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
 .setTitle("Warnings")
 .setDescription(`${victim} got warned by ${message.author}!`)
 .setColor("GREEN")
 .setFooter(`Moderator : ${message.author.username}`)
 .setTimestamp()
 
 message.channel.send(embed)
 }
});

client.on("message", async (message) => {
    if(message.content.startsWith("!mute")) {
      if(message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) {
        let member = message.mentions.members.first()
          if(!member) {
            message.channel.send("Mention someone to mute!")
          } else {
            member.roles.add("813876389475385394")
            let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
              .setTitle("Mutes")
              .setDescription(`${victim} got kicked by ${message.author}!`)
              .setColor("GREEN")
              .setFooter(`Moderator : ${message.author.username}`)
              .setTimestamp()
            message.channel.send(embed)
          };
       };
    };
});
```

If there are some questions ask it
I will really appreciate it if you will help! <3

[he is kinda crazy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7jez.png)

Comment: Can you screenshot what exactly is happening when you post a message?

Comment: What error is thrown? It makes debugging so much easier

Comment: @JoeMoore I don't think they're receiving an error. I think everything is working but from what it sounds like, it's still sending responses they don't want the bot to send.

Comment: i did added screenshot @QuazArxx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems are that you have two `onMessage` events in your code (you only need one) and that you never check if the author of a message is a bot it's self. That check is important because the bot responds to any message because of your first `onMessage` event.

This one:

```
client.on("message", async (message) => {
    let victim = message.mentions.users.first()
    if (!victim) message.reply("mention someone to warn.")
    else {
        let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle("Warnings")
            .setDescription(`${victim} got warned by ${message.author}!`)
            .setColor("GREEN")
            .setFooter(`Moderator : ${message.author.username}`)
            .setTimestamp()

        message.channel.send(embed)
    }
});
```

In that block you never check for any commands so it always fires.

**Now the actual problem and consequent fix.** *Note: I know it's a long sentence but bear with me*

First your bot reacts on any message and checks if someone was mentioned in that message. If thats not the case, it replies which mentions the original author, which in turn triggers the event again. This time someone is mentioned (because of the reply) and the bot sends the embed, to which it reacts again and the cycle restarts.

Now to fix your particular issue, all you need to do is, check if the author of a message is a bot. You do that with `if (message.author.bot) return;`.

So it should look like this:

```
client.on("message", async (message) => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    let victim = message.mentions.users.first()
    if (!victim) message.reply("mention someone to warn.")
    else {
        let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle("Warnings")
            .setDescription(`${victim} got warned by ${message.author}!`)
            .setColor("GREEN")
            .setFooter(`Moderator : ${message.author.username}`)
            .setTimestamp()

        message.channel.send(embed)
    }
});
```

That fixes your original issue however now you have the problem that your bot always reacts with both events.

[image]

As you can see, the bot sends two messages. This is why you only need **one** `onMessage` event. All you have to do is put both your commands into one event. It should look a little something like this:

```
client.on("message", async (message) => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (message.content.startsWith("!mute")) {
        if (message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) {
            let member = message.mentions.members.first();
            if (!member) {
                message.channel.send("Mention someone to mute!")
            } else {
                member.roles.add("813876389475385394");
                let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setTitle("Mutes")
                    .setDescription(`${victim} got kicked by ${message.author}!`)
                    .setColor("GREEN")
                    .setFooter(`Moderator : ${message.author.username}`)
                    .setTimestamp();
                
                message.channel.send(embed);
            };
        };
    } else if (message.content.startsWith("!warn")) {
        let victim = message.mentions.users.first();
        if (!victim) return message.reply("mention someone to warn.");
        
        let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle("Warnings")
            .setDescription(`${victim} got warned by ${message.author}!`)
            .setColor("GREEN")
            .setFooter(`Moderator : ${message.author.username}`)
            .setTimestamp();

        message.channel.send(embed);
    }
    
});
```

This is a very basic version of a command handler but it works. If you want to learn about a little more advanced version, see [here](https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/#individual-command-files).

Comment: bro, tysm, it is an awesome guide

Comment: you can mark the answer as correct and upvote it if you found it helpfull

Comment: but wait, you fixed the last problem but now mute command doesn't work

Comment: I changed nothing on your actual `mute` code. When I tested it, it worked till the `if (!member)` part.

Comment: Uhm, okay, your answer is actually useful and I will mark it as useful but, can you help me with mute command, please

Comment: add me on discord and we can talk about it: Worthy Alpaca#2063